# MySQL Connection Error in Java - com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have been trying to connect my java application to a MySQL database and have used the following lines of code:

```
import java.sql.*; 
public class AcceptValues extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

             String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name";
             String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
             String userName = "root";
             String password = "";
             try {
             Class.forName(driver);
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
             out.print("Connection estd");
             Statement st = conn.createStatement();
             st.executeQuery("insert into table_name values(2, 'testing');");
             }
             conn.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 out.print("Error : " +e.getMessage());
             }
        }
}
```

I have also set the classname to mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar which I downloaded from the mysql website. But I still am not able to connect to the database using the above lines of code and is throwing the exeption **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** as an error.

I'm new to java development and any help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Print the stack trace using only e,change e.getMessage() to e

Comment: Use e.printStackTrace(), and post the error stack trace. And explain what you mean by "I have also set the classname to mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar". This jar is in your WEB-INF/lib folder, right?

Comment: I did not include the mysql-connector file in WEB-INF/lib folder. Now that I did, everything is working fine. Thanks JB Nizet for spotting the error!

Comment: The jars in WEB-INF/lib are the classpath of your webapp. If your webapp needs a library, this library must be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
Its not enough to just add the jar in your built path.
Even I had the same issue at the start.

Comment: Or, better stilll, learn how to use maven, gradle, or some other build management tool that will *do all this for you*.

Answer (score 3):

Here is you answer,

right click on project properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> add Jar to your project(which you already downloaded)

don't right you connection information in servlet file create separate file for connection

call the class whenever you need

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DBConn {

private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String userName = "root";
private String password = "root";
private Connection con = null;

private void getConnection() {

     try {
         Class.forName(driver);
         if(con == null){
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
         }
         System.out.print("Connection estd");
     }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Error : " +e.getMessage());
    }
}


/**for desktop application */
public static void main(String[] arg){

    DBConn con = new DBConn();
    con.getConnection();
  }
}
```

You can also getconnection in your sevelet using following code

```
import java.sql.*; 
public class AcceptValues extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   DBConn con = new DBConn();
   con.getConnection();
}
}
```

this sample code but you can make it more efficient this is just sample,

please mention full error/exception information

Answer (score 0):

### the exeption com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as an error.

i met this problem, in most case, there are two reasons behind this problem. one is lack of the mysql jar file, the two is losing  sight of starting the the mysql service.